# iOS 14 bug with date picker toolbar

Tags: swift, datepicker, storyboard, toolbar, ios14

The toolbar is higher than the date picker, is this a bug? or I do something wrong?

[image]

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showDatePicker()
    }
    
    func showDatePicker(){
        //Formate Date
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact
        
        //ToolBar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar();
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker));
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker));
        
        toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)
        
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        textField.inputView = datePicker
        
    }
    
    @objc func donedatePicker(){
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        textField.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    @objc func cancelDatePicker(){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Yes I know that I can go back to preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels, but Its Interesting why does it acting like this

Comment: did you figure out?

Comment: No, still nothing, just rolled back to .wheels

Comment: datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
if #available(iOS 14, *) {
datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
datePicker.sizeToFit()
}
         datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleDatePicker), for: .valueChanged)
         inputView = datePicker

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve your requirement from this

Objective C

```
 if (@available(iOS 13.4, *)) {
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyleWheels;
        [datePicker sizeToFit];
    }
```

In Swift

```
    if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        datePicker.sizeToFit()
    }
```

Comment: @Serj Semenov find out above answer I hope it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try it

```
 if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
    datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To set UIDatePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle to .wheels is necessary indeed but not enough.

In order to show the picker you have to set the frame as well, something like this snippet:

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {

    picker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 250.0)
    picker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 250.0)
    picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
    picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
}
```

Answer (score -1):

fixed this issue. I tried below code.

Hope so it will helpful for you. Best of Luck !!!

```
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
        let gregorian: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!
        let currentDate: NSDate = NSDate()
        let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
        
        components.year =  -1
        let minDate: NSDate = gregorian.date(byAdding: components as DateComponents, to: currentDate as Date, options: NSCalendar.Options(rawValue: 0))! as NSDate
        
        datePicker.minimumDate = minDate as Date
        if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
            datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 72.0)
            
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        dateField.inputView = datePicker
        
        let toolbar = UIToolbar();
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        
        //done button & cancel button
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: self, action: #selector(ReservationTableViewController.doneDatePicker))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ReservationTableViewController.cancelDatePicker))
        
        toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)
        
        
        // add toolbar to textField
        self.dateField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ReservationTableViewController.datePickerValueChanged), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
```

Comment: Well, you just basically added "datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 72.0)" but if something will change then you need to change this part, and it's a bad solution to just hardcode the height

Comment: I don't thing show. I checked all the different devices. it works fine.